# First sheaf cohomology $H^1(\mathscr{O}_D, \mathbb{D})=0$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Given a finite divisor$$D=p_1+\dots +p_m -q_1 -\dots -q_n$$on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$, does it necessarily follow that the first sheaf cohomology group equals zero, i.e.$$H^1(\mathscr{O}_D, \mathbb{D})=0?$$

Comment: You mean $H^1(\mathbb D, \mathcal O_{\mathbb D}(D))$, right? Or what do you mean?

Comment: Assuming you mean $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{D}}(D)$: any divisor on $\mathbb{D}$ is principal, so $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{D}}(D)$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{D}}$, and of course its higher cohomology is trivial.